# Django WhiteNoise configuration is incompatible with WhiteNoise v4.0

Tags: python, django

I am trying to deploy my Django webapp on Heroku. I have been facing this same error everytime I try to deploy.

> ImportError: 
>          Your WhiteNoise configuration is incompatible with WhiteNoise v4.0
>          This can be fixed by following the upgrade instructions at:
>          http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0
>    !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
>          See traceback above for details.
>          You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
>          Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
>             $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
>          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
>    !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
>    !     Push failed

I visited the link to make the changes as the documentation suggests. It required me to remove any mention from the the wsgi.py file and I had to add it to the middleware in settings.py and change the static storage.

```
#settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
.
.
.
.
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

I am following this tutorial (https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/09/how-to-deploy-django-applications-on-heroku.html)

I'm not sure what is causing this error. Whitenoise updates are applied and the static files are in place as well.

The project works like a charm on local server but im just not able to deploy it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you commit the changes you made to `wsgi.py` to git?

Comment: If your project works locally but not on Heroku that suggests you have changes which aren't committed. "git heroku push master" is what you run _after_ you've committed, it won't commit changes for you automatically.

Comment: I tried to commit before pushing its throwing the same error followed by a couple of more errors (error while collecting static)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage
```

alias has now been removed. Instead you should use the correct import path:

```
whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage
```

Source [Link](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0)

Comment: Thank you @skillmuggler

Comment: I find your answer confusing because he was already using
`STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
`

Answer (score 4):

in wsgi.py use

`from whitenoise import WhiteNoise`

instead of

`from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise`

Comment: Update this import in `settings.py`, and use `application = WhiteNoise(application)` instead of `application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)` in `settigns.py`.

Answer (score 1):

I basically followed the instruction on this page to [fixe it](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0).

The WSGI integration option for Django (which involved editing wsgi.py) has been removed. Instead, you should add WhiteNoise to your middleware list in settings.py and remove any reference to WhiteNoise from wsgi.py.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently from version 4.0 of WhiteNoise some setup options have been changed. The WSGI integration with django has been removed which include editing the wsgi.py file; so you should remove any reference to wsgi.py file and add WhiteNoise to the middleware list in your settings.py file instead. http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0

The WhiteNoise middleware should be placed directly under the Django SecurityMiddleware and above all the other middlewares [http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#:~:text=Enable%20WhiteNoise,middleware](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#:%7E:text=Enable%20WhiteNoise,middleware).

. [whitenoise middleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxpKH.png)

And also, the "whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage" alias has been changed to
"whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage" which is again in your settings.py file i.e.
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

Answer (score -1):

You can face this error if you DEBUG is set TRUE.

Be sure you get this settings for the production: `DEBUG = FALSE`